# One column PDF from cas-dc two column class file

Tags: document-classes, columns, elsarticle, els-cas

I am preparing a manuscript using Elsevier's `cas-dc.cls` class for two column output. I am looking for a way to produce a single column output PDF file using the `cas-dc.cls` for review.

The documentation for Elsevier LaTeX instructions are [here](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions) and the CAS class documentation is [here](https://support.stmdocs.in/wiki/index.php?title=Elsarticle_-_CAS). I have gone through both but could not find a way to produce a single column output file using the `cas-dc.cls` class file. The documentation does not give details of the options that can be used with this class. It just tells that the class can be used as following:

```
\documentclass[<options>]{cas-dc}
```

However, no details of the `options` are given in the documentation.

I have also tried replacing `cas-dc` with `cas-sc` in the `documentclass` declaration of my LaTeX document, but this yields formatting problems.

Here is the MWE of what I am using:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-dc}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\shorttitle{Leveraging social media news}

\title [mode = title]{This is a specimen $a_b$ title}                      
\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here.
\end{abstract}
\maketitle
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I change `cas-dc` to `cas-sc` in your example, it works fine.  Can you show an example that errors when you change to `cas-sc`?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, Code for the floats i.e. figures and tables creates problems and has to be changed.

Comment: Well, of course, if you change from double to single column the layout changes.  But in your question you said there are errors, but I see none in your MWE.

Comment: The errors were due to some mistakes in the code which I have corrected. Now, there are only layout problems as you pointed out. I have edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: Okay, glad you found the errors.  However your example shows no “formatting problems” ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7MjO.png)), so it's hard to give you any useful advice.  Please post an example document that when compiled will show these problems. Also, you can't make single-column with `cas-dc` (`dc` stands for double column and `sc` for single column).

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why this happens, but what I did was I copy-pasted the folder from this overleaf link https://www.overleaf.com/project/6102e59068dbe00d6a2d92cc and edited from that. After digging a bit, I found a weird reason why this happens. It seems that we need to include a thumbnails folder to convert it to double-column format. I'm sorry I could have added this as a comment but don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/214155)

Comment: I'm sorry I really don't know why this happens but found a way to get over it. Please be easy on me.